# Upload múltiplo de imagens com problemas

Tags: php, mysql

Meu sistema de upload não dava erro até testar num servidor ali que o mesmo me retorna erro de permissão de pasta, pra quando ele vai gerar a pasta com o título que vem pelo método post, não gera a pasta e não faz o múltiplo upload. Já mudei permissão de pasta com o pessoal do servidor e nada.

Segue o código do arquivo :

```
// Incluir o arquivo conecta.php que faz a conexão com o banco de dados
include "conecta.php" ;

//Dou um Extract e jogo o valor dentro da variavel $arq1
  extract($_POST);
  $arq1=$_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
//Seleciona a ultima entrada do banco na tabela galeria
  $s_trab = "SELECT ID
                 FROM noticias";
  $t_trab = mysql_query($s_trab) or die(mysql_error());  
  $trab   = mysql_fetch_array($t_trab);
//Dou um nome para a foto que será o ultimo id + 1
  $nome = $trab[id] + 1;
//crio um nome único para a imagem
  $arq1 = $nome.$_FILES['imagem']['name'];
//cria um nome temporário para mover o arquivo
  $arq1_tmp = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
//Comando para mover o arquivo para o diretório especificado, aplicando o nome definido anteriormente
  move_uploaded_file($arq1_tmp,"foto_noticias/".$arq1);

// galeria 
$p = 0;
$countArr = count($_FILES['arquivo']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $countArr; $i++){

  // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
  if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i]))
  {

    $arquivo_tmp  = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $nome         = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i];

    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png;.bmp', $extensao))
    {
      // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
      $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

      if($p == 0){
        $trataEspaco = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['titulo']);
        @mkdir('foto_noticias/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/');
        $p = 1;
      }

      // Concatena a pasta com o nome
      $destino = 'foto_noticias/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/' . $novoNome;

      // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
      if(@move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino))
      {
        echo "Fotos salvas com sucesso!";
      }
      else
       echo "Permissao!";
    }
    else
      echo ".jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;"; 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
  }

}
// fim da galeria

//Gravando o nome do arquivo e a legenda na tabela do banco de dados  

  $i_galeria = "INSERT INTO noticias (  post_title , post_name, imagem, post_content, post_date, status) VALUES 
  (  '$_POST[titulo]', '$_POST[chamada]', '$arq1', '$_POST[descricao]', now(), $_POST[status])";
    mysql_query($i_galeria) or die (mysql_error());

//Retorno a página de formulário
echo "
 <script language='javascript'>
 alert('Dados adquididos com sucesso!');
 parent.location='noticias_admin.php';
   </script>
";
?>
```

Comment: Hoje vou fazer a papel daquele cara chato que diz assim: **Você poderia postar exatamente qual é a mensagem de erro retornada na exceção?**

Comment: @C.Bohok ele retorna assim : permissão! permissão! e não grava nada

Comment: @ACompanhiaWeb A pasta com o valor de $trataEspaco não está sendo criada?

Comment: Mesmo após ter liberado a permissão da pasta com o pessoal do servidor continua dando erro de permissão?

Comment: Deu certo pessoal obrigado, obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o erro esteja na criação da pasta e so declaras `$trataEspaço` se `$p = 0`
,Tenta assim:

```
$countArr = count($_FILES['arquivo']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $countArr; $i++){

  // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo 
  if(isset($_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i]))
  {

    $arquivo_tmp  = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $nome         = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'][$i];

    // Pega a extensao
    $extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

    // Converte a extensao para mimusculo
    $extensao = strtolower($extensao);

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png;.bmp', $extensao))
    {
      // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
      $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;
      $trataEspaco = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['titulo']);

      if (!file_exists('/foto_noticias/galeria/' . $trataEspaco)) {
          mkdir('/foto_noticias/galeria/' . $trataEspaco, 0777, true);
      }
      // Concatena a pasta com o nome
      $destino = '/foto_noticias/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/' . $novoNome;

      // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
      if(move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino))
      {
        echo "Fotos salvas com sucesso!";
      }
      else
       echo "Permissao!";
    }
    else
      echo ".jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;"; 
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
  }

}
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar **acredito** que o php não consegue encontrar o caminho para isso tenta obter o caminho absoluto e juntar ao caminho que já possuis, assim:

### PHP >= 5.3.0

Usa:
 ***__DIR__***

Exemplo:

```
 $destino = __DIR__ . '/foto_noticias/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/' . $novoNome;
```

### PHP < 5.3.0

Usa: ***dirname(__FILE__)***

exemplo:

```
 $destino = dirname(__FILE__) . '/foto_noticias/galeria/'.$trataEspaco.'/' . $novoNome;
```

**Nota**

Substitui o `str_replace` por  `preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['titulo']);` porque acho que vai garantir mais **segurança** na hora de criar a pasta, este mesmo remove todos os caracteres não *alfa-numéricos*